# Android: How to hide soft keyboard on screen off?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing a screenlock app. It starts fullscreen activity when screen turns off. And there's a problem: if user was using a soft keyboard when screen was turned off, the keyboard does not goes off the screen. And it looks like fullscreen activity and keyboard above it. So user can't unlock the device because back and home buttons are disabled and keyboard hides the unlock area.

I've tried to use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

where view is getCurrentFocus(), getWindow().getDecorView and some view on my layout - there is no any effect because the keyboard was called by another app.

Also, part of my manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" .../>
```

it doesn't work too. So, how can I hide the keyboard globaly?

Comment: android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" into field bywhich keyboard get focused.

Comment: check this property android:configChanges

Comment: android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" does not work. I can't set it on third-party's soft which called the keyboard

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I added string android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden" to my manifest, and in activity class I overrided the onConfigurationChange() method. I put Log.d("111", "test"); in it. So, it does not matter, is there a keyboard on screen or not, the Log does not appears

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`
For details information you may visit this link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: No, it doesn't work too. I've checked it just right now. And stateAlwaysHidden means "The soft keyboard is always hidden when the activity's main window has input focus.". My activity has no input focus